# How to disable code signing on Azure Dev Ops - Still getting “Error signing output with public key from file mssharedlibsn1024.snk - File not found”

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, code-signing

We've disabled our code signing in our dev branch build pipe, and it fails with the following error:

> Error CS7027: Error signing output with public key from file
>   '......\SigningCertificates\mssharedlibsn1024.snk' -- File not found.

It keeps looking for the file even after we removed it from the solution and the project and the source control.

When I tried enabling the code signing to overcome this error, I got a different one instead (because of the code signing that occurred):

> Error: The process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe'
>   failed with exit code 1 Initialization method
>
> Microsoft.Crm.Sales.ProductivityBot.Test.Cards.EntityCardArgsTests.Setup
>   threw exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Crm.Sales.ProductivityBot, Version=0.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8013141A) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Strong name
>   validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A).

The above error comes from the test project which is not signed.

So it goes down to 2 questions:

1. How do we get rid of the snk file error and truly disable the code signing?
2. In case the code signing runs (such as cases we do want to run the tests), how do we configure the tests project to use the signed tested "main" project?

Comment: Disable the snk sign problem using [visual studio](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/1040107/StrongNamedAssembly.SigningTab.png)

Comment: ever find a solution?  you might want to clean to true under get sources so doesn't have any older ones lying around.  also you can add a command line task to the pipeline to add exclusion for your delayed signing key: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\sn.exe" -Vr *,asdfdfasdfasf  where asdfadfasdf is your public key.  see sn.exe documentation for more info.